# Compare date in multiple rows and calculate the downtime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to calculate the downtime for a train from a service record, below is a sample scenario

[image]

There can be multiple jobs running simultaneous for a train which can overlap at times

For:

1. **Job_number 1** the date diff between the work start and end date is 360 Minute
2. **Job_number 2** the date diff between the work start and end date is 60 Minute but this overlap with Job_number 1 so we shouldn't consider this
3. **Job_number 3** the date diff between the work start and end date is 45 Minute but this partially overlap with Job_number 1 so we should consider only 10 Minute

So the actual down time should be 360 Minute (Job 1) + 0 Minute (Job 2) + 10 Minute (Job 3) = ***370 Minute***

My desired output is :-

[image]

I'm having 20 trains as of now for which I need to calculate the downtime as above

How do I do this?

Sample Data script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tb_ServiceMemo](
    [Job_Number] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Train_Number] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Work_Start_Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Work_Completed_Date] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO [dbo].[tb_ServiceMemo]
    VALUES (1,1,'01-08-2018 12:35','01-08-18 18:35'),
        (2,1,'01-08-2018 14:20','01-08-18 15:20'),
        (3,1,'01-08-2018 18:00','01-08-18 18:45')
```

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: DDL & DMLs included, my attempt on this was using cursor which is way too complicate and expensive so I'm looking for new approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem, but it is tricky because it has start and end times.

The idea for the solution is to determine when an outage starts.  What is the characteristic?  Well, the period starts at a time where there is no overlap with preceding work.  The tricky part is that more than one "work" effort could start at the same time (although your data does not show this).

Once you know the time when an outage starts, you can use a cumulative sum to assign a group to each record and then simply aggregate by that group (and other information).

The following query should do what you want:

```
with starts as (
      select sm.*,
             (case when exists (select 1
                                from tb_ServiceMemo sm2
                                where sm2.Train_Number = sm.Train_Number and
                                      sm2.Work_Start_Date < sm.Work_Start_Date and
                                      sm2.Work_Completed_Date >= sm.Work_Start_Date
                               )
                   then 0 else 1
              end) as isstart
      from tb_ServiceMemo sm
     )
select Train_Number, min(Work_Start_Date) as outage_start_date, max(Work_Completed_Date) as outage_end_date,
       datediff(minute, min(Work_Start_Date), max(Work_Completed_Date))
from (select s.*, sum(isstart) over (partition by Train_Number order by Work_Start_Date) as grp
      from starts s
     ) s
group by Train_Number, grp;
```

In this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=59be71942416f2b65a80f7a030e06601), I added a few more rows to show how the code works in different scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Gaps and Islands in Sequences problem.

You can try to use recursive CTE, get the minute during every row.
then use every `MAX` and `MIN` DateTime to calculate the result.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT  [Train_Number], [Work_Start_Date] ,[Work_Completed_Date]
   FROM [tb_ServiceMemo]
   UNION ALL
   SELECT [Train_Number], DATEADD(minute,1,[Work_Start_Date]) ,[Work_Completed_Date]
   FROM CTE 
   WHERE DATEADD(minute,1,[Work_Start_Date]) <= [Work_Completed_Date]
),CTE2 AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT Train_Number,
                   Work_Start_Date,
                   MAX(Work_Completed_Date) OVER(PARTITION BY Train_Number ORDER BY Work_Completed_Date DESC) MAX_Time
   FROM CTE 
),CTE_RESULT AS (
    SELECT *,datediff(mi,MAX_Time,Work_Start_Date) - row_number() over(PARTITION BY Train_Number ORDER BY Work_Start_Date) grp
    FROM CTE2
)
SELECT Train_Number,sum(time_diff)
FROM (
    SELECT Train_Number,DATEDIFF(MI,MIN(Work_Start_Date),MAX(Work_Start_Date)) time_diff
    FROM CTE_RESULT
    GROUP BY Train_Number,grp   
)t1
GROUP BY Train_Number
option ( MaxRecursion 0 );
```

[sqlfiddle](https://rextester.com/SCTF65893)

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test this on my actual data, will let you know tomorrow

Comment: The code works. The correctly marked answer below is the best in terms of performance, appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1):

This is the infamous gaps and islands problem with dates. The following is a solution that uses a recursive CTE. It might be a little tough to understand if you aren't used to working with them, I commented all parts that might need clarifying.

I also added a few more examples to contemplate different scenarios, such as different days on periods and overlapping times exactly at the start/end.

Example setup:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tb_ServiceMemo') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tb_ServiceMemo

CREATE TABLE #tb_ServiceMemo(
    Job_Number INT, -- This is an INT not VARCHAR!! (even the name says so)
    Train_Number INT, -- This one also!!
    Work_Start_Date DATETIME,
    Work_Completed_Date DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #tb_ServiceMemo (
    Job_Number,
    Train_Number,
    Work_Start_Date,
    Work_Completed_Date)
VALUES

    -- Total time train 1: 6h 10m (370m)
    (1,1,'2018-08-01 12:35','2018-08-01 18:35'), -- Make sure to write date literals in ISO format (yyyy-MM-dd) to avoid multiple interpretations
    (2,1,'2018-08-01 14:20','2018-08-01 15:20'),
    (3,1,'2018-08-01 18:00','2018-08-01 18:45'),

    -- Total time train 2: 2h (120m)
    (4,2,'2018-08-01 12:00','2018-08-01 12:10'),
    (5,2,'2018-08-01 12:15','2018-08-01 12:20'),
    (6,2,'2018-08-01 13:15','2018-08-01 13:45'),
    (9,2,'2018-08-01 13:45','2018-08-01 15:00'),

    -- Total time train 3: 3h 45m (225m)
    (7,3,'2018-08-01 23:30','2018-08-02 00:30'),
    (8,3,'2018-08-02 00:15','2018-08-02 03:15'),

    -- Total time train 4: 2d 8h 15m (3375m)
    (10,4,'2018-08-01 23:00','2018-08-03 23:00'),
    (11,4,'2018-08-02 00:15','2018-08-04 07:15')
```

The solution:

```
;WITH TimeLapses AS
(
    -- Recursive Anchor: Find the minimum Jobs for each train that doesn't overlap with previous Jobs
    SELECT
        InitialJobNumber = T.Job_Number,
        JobNumber = T.Job_Number,
        TrainNumber = T.Train_Number,
        IntervalStart = T.Work_Start_Date,
        IntervalEnd = T.Work_Completed_Date,
        JobExtensionPath = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), T.Job_Number), -- Will store the chained jobs together for clarity
        RecursionLevel = 1
    FROM
        #tb_ServiceMemo AS T
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT
                'Job doesn''t overlap with previous Jobs (by train)'
            FROM
                #tb_ServiceMemo AS S
            WHERE
                S.Train_Number = T.Train_Number AND
                S.Job_Number < T.Job_Number AND
                S.Work_Completed_Date >= T.Work_Start_Date AND -- Conditions for the periods to overlap
                S.Work_Start_Date <= T.Work_Completed_Date)

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive Union: Chain overlapping Jobs by train and keep intervals boundaries (min & max)
    SELECT
        InitialJobNumber = L.InitialJobNumber,
        JobNumber = T.Job_Number,
        TrainNumber = L.TrainNumber,
        IntervalStart = CASE -- Minimum of both starts
            WHEN L.IntervalStart <= T.Work_Start_Date THEN L.IntervalStart
            ELSE T.Work_Start_Date END,
        IntervalEnd = CASE -- Maximum of both ends
            WHEN L.IntervalEnd >= T.Work_Completed_Date THEN L.IntervalEnd
            ELSE T.Work_Completed_Date END,
        JobExtensionPath = L.JobExtensionPath + '->' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), T.Job_Number),
        RecursionLevel = L.RecursionLevel + 1
    FROM
        TimeLapses AS L -- Recursive CTE!
        INNER JOIN #tb_ServiceMemo AS T ON
            L.TrainNumber = T.Train_Number AND
            T.Work_Completed_Date >= L.IntervalStart AND -- Conditions for the periods to overlap
            T.Work_Start_Date <= L.IntervalEnd
    WHERE
        L.JobNumber < T.Job_Number -- Prevent joining in both directions (that would be "<>") to avoid infinite loops
),
MaxRecursionLevelByTrain AS
(
    /* 
        Max recursion level will hold the longest interval for each train, as there might be recursive paths that skips some jobs. For example: Train 1's job 1 will
        join with Job 2 and Job 3 on the first recursive level, then Job 2 will join with Job 3 on the next recursion. The higher the recursion level the more Jobs we
        are taking into account for the longest interval.
        We also need to group by InitialJobNumber as there might be different, idependent gaps for each train.
    */
    SELECT
        TrainNumber = T.TrainNumber,
        InitialJobNumber = T.InitialJobNumber,
        MaxRecursionLevel = MAX(T.RecursionLevel)
    FROM
        TimeLapses AS T
    GROUP BY
        T.TrainNumber,
        T.InitialJobNumber
),
ExpandedLapses AS
(
    SELECT
        TrainNumber = T.TrainNumber,
        InitialJobNumber = M.InitialJobNumber,
        IntervalStart = T.IntervalStart,
        IntervalEnd = T.IntervalEnd,
        DownTime = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, T.IntervalStart, T.IntervalEnd),
        JobExtensionPath = T.JobExtensionPath,
        RecursionLevel = T.RecursionLevel
    FROM
        MaxRecursionLevelByTrain AS M
        INNER JOIN TimeLapses AS T ON 
            M.TrainNumber = T.TrainNumber AND
            M.MaxRecursionLevel = T.RecursionLevel AND
            M.InitialJobNumber = T.InitialJobNumber
)
SELECT
    TrainNumber = E.TrainNumber,
    TotalDownTime = SUM(DownTime)
FROM
    ExpandedLapses AS E
GROUP BY
    E.TrainNumber
```

And these are the partial results from each CTE, so you can see each step:

**TimeLapses**:

```
InitialJobNumber    JobNumber   TrainNumber IntervalStart               IntervalEnd                 JobExtensionPath    RecursionLevel
1                   1           1           2018-08-01 12:35:00.000     2018-08-01 18:35:00.000     1                   1
1                   2           1           2018-08-01 12:35:00.000     2018-08-01 18:35:00.000     1->2                2
1                   3           1           2018-08-01 12:35:00.000     2018-08-01 18:45:00.000     1->3                2
1                   3           1           2018-08-01 12:35:00.000     2018-08-01 18:45:00.000     1->2->3             3
4                   4           2           2018-08-01 12:00:00.000     2018-08-01 12:10:00.000     4                   1
5                   5           2           2018-08-01 12:15:00.000     2018-08-01 12:20:00.000     5                   1
6                   6           2           2018-08-01 13:15:00.000     2018-08-01 13:45:00.000     6                   1
6                   9           2           2018-08-01 13:15:00.000     2018-08-01 15:00:00.000     6->9                2
7                   8           3           2018-08-01 23:30:00.000     2018-08-02 03:15:00.000     7->8                2
7                   7           3           2018-08-01 23:30:00.000     2018-08-02 00:30:00.000     7                   1
10                  10          4           2018-08-01 23:00:00.000     2018-08-03 23:00:00.000     10                  1
10                  11          4           2018-08-01 23:00:00.000     2018-08-04 07:15:00.000     10->11              2
```

**MaxRecursionLevelByTrain**:

```
TrainNumber     InitialJobNumber    MaxRecursionLevel
1               1                   3
2               4                   1
2               5                   1
2               6                   2
3               7                   2
4               10                  2
```

**ExtendedLapses**:

```
TrainNumber     InitialJobNumber    IntervalStart               IntervalEnd                 DownTime        JobExtensionPath    RecursionLevel
1               1                   2018-08-01 12:35:00.000     2018-08-01 18:45:00.000     370             1->2->3             3
2               4                   2018-08-01 12:00:00.000     2018-08-01 12:10:00.000     10              4                   1
2               5                   2018-08-01 12:15:00.000     2018-08-01 12:20:00.000     5               5                   1
2               6                   2018-08-01 13:15:00.000     2018-08-01 15:00:00.000     105             6->9                2
3               7                   2018-08-01 23:30:00.000     2018-08-02 03:15:00.000     225             7->8                2
4               10                  2018-08-01 23:00:00.000     2018-08-04 07:15:00.000     3375            10->11              2
```

**Final Result**:

```
TrainNumber     TotalDownTime
1               370
2               120
3               225
4               3375
```

A few things worth mentioning:

- While this solution will definitely be faster than using a cursor, it might not be the best one available, specially if you have a huge dataset (more than 100k records). There is room for improving performance.
- You might benefit from a index on `#tb_ServiceMemo` (`Train_Number, Job_Number, Work_Start_Date`) to speed up the query.
- You might need to add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION N)` at the end of the `SELECT` statement, being `N` the max recursion level you want to try. Default is `100`, so if there are more than 100 periods that chain together for a particular train, an error message will pop up. You can use `0` as `N` for unlimited.
- Make sure that every end time is higher than the start time, and that the job numbers don't repeat, at least by each train.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one ? I added other test case to besure but I think it's OK. I also think there is more simple

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tb_ServiceMemo]
SELECT 1, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-08-01 09:35:00', 120), CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-08-01 12:45:00', 120) union
SELECT 2, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-08-01 12:35:00', 120), CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-08-01 18:35:00', 120) union
SELECT 3, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-08-01 14:20:00', 120), CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-08-01 15:20:00', 120) union
SELECT 4, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-08-01 18:00:00', 120), CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-08-01 18:45:00', 120) union
SELECT 5, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-08-01 19:00:00', 120), CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-08-01 19:45:00', 120)

SELECT [Train_Number], SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, T.[Work_Start_Date], T.Work_Completed_Date)) as Delay
FROM (
    SELECT
        [Job_Number], 
        [Train_Number],
        CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [tb_ServiceMemo] T3 WHERE T1.[Work_Start_Date] BETWEEN T3.[Work_Start_Date] AND T3.[Work_Completed_Date] AND T1.[Job_Number] <> T3.[Job_Number] AND T1.Train_Number = T3.Train_Number)
            THEN (SELECT MAX(T3.[Work_Completed_Date]) FROM [tb_ServiceMemo] T3 WHERE T1.[Work_Start_Date] BETWEEN T3.[Work_Start_Date] AND T3.[Work_Completed_Date] AND T1.[Job_Number] <> T3.[Job_Number]  AND T1.Train_Number = T3.Train_Number)
        ELSE [Work_Start_Date] END as [Work_Start_Date],
        [Work_Completed_Date]
    FROM [tb_ServiceMemo] T1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS( -- To kick off the ignored case
        SELECT T2.*
        FROM [tb_ServiceMemo] T2 
        WHERE T2.[Work_Start_Date] < T1.[Work_Start_Date] AND T2.[Work_Completed_Date] > T1.[Work_Completed_Date]
    )
) as T
GROUP BY [Train_Number]
```

The idea is to :

- ignore the result contained into another
- rewrite the start date value of each rown if she is contained into another